# Asp.net two models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get 2 models to show in 1 view but it is not working. I have tried lots of different ideas from Google but none have worked so far.

There is no error in the Error List. But when I start it I get this error.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.Models.Class1]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Namespace.Models.ParentClass]'.
```

I have a parent class containing the to child classes. If i use the @model IEnumerable<> directly at the child class it works, but not when pointed at the parent.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Ok so these are my files.

**Model1.cs**

```
public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
```

**Model2.cs**

```
public int AnotherProperty1 { get; set; }
public int AnotherProperty2 { get; set; }
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public IEnumerable<Model1> Model1 { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Model2> Model2 { get; set; }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
private ConnectContext db = new ConnectContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
var model = from m in db.model select m;
model = db.model.OrderByDescending(m => m.ID);

return View(db.model.ToList());
}
```

**Index.chstml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.ViewModel>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model1.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model2.Title)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Now with the files like this my error message is

```
CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.Model1>' does not contain a definition for 'Cover' and no extension method 'Cover' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.Model1>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: [Multiple Models in a View in ASP.NET MVC 4 / MVC 5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this working. I had to change my ViewModel, Controller and View.

**ViewModel.cs** ***(From IEnumerable to List)***

```
public List<Model1> Model1 { get; set; }
public List<Model2> Model2 { get; set; }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
private ConnectContext db = new ConnectContext();
public ActionResult Index()
   {
      ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
      vm.Model1 = (from m in db.Model1 select m).OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(3).ToList();
      vm.Model2 = (from t in db.Model2 select t).OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(3).ToList();

      return View(vm);
   }
```

**Index.cshtml**
***(So here I removed the IEnumerable and then each Foreach connects to each Model)***

```
@model Namespace.Models.ViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Model1) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Model2) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are combining 2 models to a single class and passing that class as a single model. So, at the end, it is a single model that is bound to your view, not 2 models, is not it ?

Comment: Basically yes. Because I needed access to both models I needed to put them in a Parentmodel as you can only include 1 model in your view

Answer (score 4):

If you have two and only two classes you want to pass in, have you considered using a tuple?

For example:

On the controller end,

```
var model = new Tuple<ModelType1, ModelType2>(yourModel1, yourModel2);
return View(model);
```

On the view end, you'll want this at the top, along with any using statements you may need:

```
@model Tuple<ModelType1, ModelType2>
```

To access each part in the view, `@Model.Item1` will be your `ModelType1` and `@Model.Item2` will be your `ModelType2`.

If you wind up with more than two classes, it might be a good idea for you to make a ViewModel class with properties for the various types you want to include.  (You can also cop out and add properties to the ViewBag.)

Comment: I haven't used Tuple before. I'm guessing how to use it and it's the same error as before

Comment: How exactly does the parent class "contain" the two child classes?  Are they subclasses of the parent class, or does the parent class have properties on itself to represent the child classes?

Comment: public class MainPageModel{
    public Model1 Model1{get; set;}
    public Model2 Model2{get; set;}
}

Comment: So where does the enumeration come into play?  A `List<MainPageModel>`?

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on what everything looks like on your end, but just be sure what you're passing in from the controller matches what you're putting in as the `@model` on the view. Whether it's a `List<MainPageModel>` or just a `MainPageModel`, be sure both controller and view are using the same, because based on your error, I don't think they are.

Comment: @user3147812, Your error message does not match what you indicated you class names are. Please post the models, the controller code you use to pass the model, and the view

Comment: Tuple is clever but the readability takes a hit. I would prefer a consolidated class having both objects. so that i can use Model.ChildModel1, Model.ChildModel2.

Comment: I have updated the post to reflect how my files look

Comment: Also the info I'm pulling is coming from an SQL DB

Comment: The way you have it right now, you're pulling multiple ViewModels. I'm not sure if that's what you're wanting to do or not, but we'll assume for the moment that it is. Each ViewModel has two IEnumerable properies, collections of `Model1` and `Model2`.  Because these are `IEnumerable` collections, you can't just pull properties like `Title` or `Cover` without doing yet another foreach loop first.

Comment: If you're wanting to group things together, be sure you have only an IEnumerable or List of the MainPageModel or whatever you're doing and NOT also of the Model1 and Model2.

Comment: No it should be 1 view model but with multiple rows coming from the DB in the `IEnumerable`. I have two tables in the DB and each table is connected to each Model1 & Model2. So do I need to remove `IEnumerable` from the ViewModel.cs and only have it in the View page, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

What about just making a model class with properties that makes up the two classes you need for your view?

E.g.

```
public class FirstModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SecondModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public FirstModel MyFirstModel { get; set; }
    public SecondModel MySecondModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view you use a model of ViewModel.

Comment: what do you mean by it fails?

Comment: the error i'm getting is `'Namespace.Models.ViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Cover' and no extension method 'Cover' accepting a first argument of type 'Namespace.Models.ViewModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class FirstModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SecondModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public FirstModel MyFirstModel { get; set; }
    public SecondModel MySecondModel { get; set; }
}
```

In your Controller:

```
private ConnectContext db = new ConnectContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FirstModel firstModel = //Set FirstModel Value;
    SecondModel secondModel = //Set SecondModel Value;

    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(){
        FirstModel = firstModel,
        SecondModel = secondModel
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```